# MongoDB aggregation group by query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection and I want to do an aggregation query. 

I am grouping by `alert_type` field, but I also want the list of those `alert_type` as a separate field in the output.

**Collection looks like this :**

```
db.test.insertMany([
  {
    "output_data": {
      "alert_type": "UAlert",
      "overallImpact": {
        "margin": 0.1,
        "workingCapital": 3.33
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "output_data": {
      "alert_type": "CAlert",
      "overallImpact": {
        "margin": 0.1,
        "workingCapital": 3.33
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "output_data": {
      "alert_type": "UAlert",
      "overallImpact": {
        "margin": 0.1,
        "workingCapital": 3.33
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Query that I have tried** :

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      "_id": "$output_data.alert_type",
      "alert_type": {
        "$first": "$output_data.alert_type"
      },
      "margin": {
        "$sum": "$output_data.overallImpact.margin"
      },
      "workingCapital": {
        "$sum": "$output_data.overallImpact.workingCapital"
      },
      "alert_types": {
        "$addToSet": "$output_data.alert_type"
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {'_id': 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Current output** :

```
{
  "alert_type": "UAlert",
  "margin": 0.2,
  "workingCapital": 6.66,
  "alert_types": [
    "UAlert"
  ]
}
{
  "alert_type": "CAlert",
  "margin": 0.1,
  "workingCapital": 3.33,
  "alert_types": [
    "CAlert"
  ]
}
```

**Required Output** :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "alert_type": "UAlert",
      "margin": 0.2,
      "workingCapital": 6.66,
    },
    {
      "alert_type": "CAlert",
      "margin": 0.1,
      "workingCapital": 3.33,
    }
  ],
  "alert_types": [
    "UAlert",
    "CAlert"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        "_id": "$output_data.alert_type",
        alert_type: { $first: "$output_data.alert_type" },
        margin: { $sum: "$output_data.overallImpact.margin" },
        workingCapital: { $sum: "$output_data.overallImpact.workingCapital" }
      }
    },
    /** Optional stage - Just to exclude `_id` inside each object of data array from final output */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0 }
    },
    /** Grouping on all docs, For this group stage we will have lesser docs compared to prior Group stage */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "", // Group without any condition
        data: {  $push: "$$ROOT" }, // Pushing all docs into an array
        alert_types: { $addToSet: "$alert_type" } // Adding unique values
      }
    },
    /** Optional stage - Just to exclude `_id` final output doc */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vuT6uQWL6hm)

Comment: Thank you for this answer @whoami. This is probably, a simpler solution than the accepted one, and this solves my problem too. But I think `$facet` will provide me with more flexibility in terms of changing the structure of input JSON. Please correct me I'm wrong as I have never used `$facet` before.

Comment: @mukesh.kumar : Only problem with `$facet` is each stage inside facet will be executed on entire dataset of the collection ! So you need to cautious on that, Which I've found is not needed in your case - I'm not saying it won't work but in terms of performance we're grouping on entire dataset twice, but if it works great then cool :-)

Comment: This is a very good point. I was not aware that `$facet` will be executed for the entire dataset. I will need to check the performance with more documents. Thank you for the information. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to achieve this, in a stage you do your grouping stage to get data, and in the other you find all the alert types available.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [
        {
          $group: {
            "_id": "$output_data.alert_type",
            "alert_type": {
              "$first": "$output_data.alert_type"
            },
            "margin": {
              "$sum": "$output_data.overallImpact.margin"
            },
            "workingCapital": {
              "$sum": "$output_data.overallImpact.workingCapital"
            },
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "alert_types": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            "names": {
              "$addToSet": "$output_data.alert_type"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 1,
      alert_types: "$alert_types.names"
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n-ALsU3u4QB)

Comment: Thank you. I will have to learn more about `$facet` as this looks a very powerful tool.

Comment: Just noticed that this query gives me alert_types as array of array.